# Play framework + scala

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm a complete newbie to Play framework as well as Scala. I'm stuck at the following scenario.

My frontend is coded in html. The input from a user and then reads the data in scala using HashMaps.

In html, there's a textbox by the id="replayZkUrlActual"

Scala Code on calling this page so as to read the text.

```
val formParams = request.body.asFormUrlEncoded
val replayZkUrlActual:String = formParams.get("replayZkUrlActual").flatMap(_.headOption).getOrElse(null)
```

I get the values correctly and I store the value from the textfield successfully. However, I need to display this value again whenever I click on submit button of my form in the same textbox (kind of autofill the previous value). I need "replayZkUrlActual" to display its value after clicking the submit button. 
The same page opens on clicking the submit button.
Can anyone please help.
Thanks

Comment: Read about [Twirl](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTemplates), play standard template engine. Your html is like a function which takes params at the top of the file. Ex: `@(replayZkUrlActual: String)`

Answer (score 0):

Just follow these documentation to get rid of it
https://playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaForms

I hope it will solve your problem